# JavaFx Combobox drop down list width is less on first click on Combo box

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, javafx-2

when I click on the ComboBox the first time and the popup menu list that is shown has its width very short. The second time I click on the ComboBox and the list is shown again, the width is now correct as the width of the list now aligns itself with the Combbox.

[image]

i tried to alter the width of the drop down on mouse click on the combo box. But it did not work,

```
final ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>();
combo.getStyleClass().add("combo-border");
combo.setMinWidth(100.0);
combo.setEditable(true);
combo.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
        combo.setMinWidth(100.0); // Did not work
        //csectCombo.setPrefWidth(100.0); // Did not work
    }
});
```

I am using Javafx 2.2. Is there any workaround for this?

From the below post, it says that is the known bug in JavaFx 2 and has been fixed in JavaFx 8.

http://tech.chitgoks.com/2013/09/20/width-of-combobox-popup-list-is-too-small-in-java-fx-2/

Comment: call the `combo.setWidth(100.0)` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
final ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<String>();
combo.getStyleClass().add("combo-border");
combo.setMinWidth(100.0);
combo.setEditable(true);
combo.setPrefWidth(combo.getMinWidth());
```